# Convert UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt> to UInt in Swift

Tags: swift

I got from a function Swift result in type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>`

Can I cast it to `UInt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `memory` property to access the underlying data.

```
let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt> = funcReturningMutablePtr()
let theValue: UInt = ptr.memory
```

The type annotations are for clarity, but are not necessary.